# Integral with Bessel function

Tags: integration, special-functions, approximation, approximation-theory, bessel-functions

Let $n$ be half an odd integer, say $n=k+1/2, k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Let $q\geq 1$. I would like to calculate (or approximate) the following integral:
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\left(\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cdot 1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots (2k+1) \frac{J_{k+\frac 12}(t)}{t^{k+ \frac 12}}\right)^q t\ dt.
$$

Any ideas or references will be very helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe the explicit statement of the function $J$ could be helpful?

Comment: @awllower: Which ine would you propose?I've tried few representations-did not work. Thank you.

Comment: @Jack: I don't know if [tag:bessel] is a good tag name. I also don't think that adding new tags should be done without consulting the community via the [meta] site.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: good point, I'll post a proposal on Meta to create a specific tag for Bessel-functions-related questions.

Comment: Here it is: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16695/about-the-creation-of-a-bessel-functions-tag

Answer (score 3):

Due to [Rayleigh's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) we have:

$$\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{J_{k+1/2}(t)}{t^{k+1/2}}=(-1)^k\left(\frac{1}{t}\frac{d}{dt}\right)^k \frac{\sin t}{t}\tag{1}$$
and since:
$$\frac{\sin t}{t}=\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^m\,t^{2m}}{(2m+1)!}$$
we have:
$$\left(\frac{1}{t}\frac{d}{dt}\right)\frac{\sin t}{t}=\sum_{m=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^m(2m)t^{2m-2}}{(2m+1)!}=(-1)\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^m (2m+2)t^{2m}}{(2m+3)!},$$
$$\left(\frac{1}{t}\frac{d}{dt}\right)^k\frac{\sin t}{t}=(-1)^k\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^m (2m+2k)\cdot\ldots\cdot(2m+2)t^{2m}}{(2m+2k+1)!}$$
so:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}(2k+1)!!\cdot\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{J_{k+1/2}(t)}{t^{k+1/2}}&=&\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^m (2m+2k)!!(2k+1)!!}{(2m+2k+1)!(2m)!!}\,t^{2m}\\&=&\sum_{m=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^m \binom{m+k}{m}}{\binom{2m+2k+1}{2m}}\cdot\frac{t^{2m}}{(2m)!}.\end{eqnarray*}\tag{2}$$
Now a really good approximation for the LHS of $(2)$ is simply given by:
$$(2k+1)!!\cdot\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{J_{k+1/2}(t)}{t^{k+1/2}}\approx \exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{4k+6}\right).\tag{3}$$
$\hspace2in$[image: Approximation for $k=3$]
$\hspace2in\qquad$ Approximation for $k=3$

Hence the starting integral can be approximated by:

> $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}t\,\exp\left(-\frac{qt^2}{4k+6}\right)\,dt=\frac{2k+3}{q}.$$